# I would like to burn an ISO on a DVD using Windows 10 built in burning tool. How to make sure it will finalize it?

Tags: windows-10, dvd-burning

I want to burn an ISO file using the built in Windows 10 burning program and the burned DVD must be manipulation proof after that (finalized). I cannon find any options for that. The only option Windows gives me is "check medium after burning".
Where can I change it to "finalize" DVD after burning?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, using Windows 10 Native Tools,

Set up the contents, burn to DVD.

A progress window appears, showing the disc burner's progress. When the progress window disappears, Windows has finished burning the disc.

Close your disc-burning session by ejecting the disc.

This is what Windows 10 does burning a DVD.

If you wish to be more certain that nothing else will be written, use Write Once DVDs and when Windows 10 completes the process and the disk ejected, it will not take any more content.

This uses the built-in Windows tools as requested.

Comment: Closing the session is not the same as finalizing the disc. The later sets the disc to non-modifiable, which is a requirement for some agencies.

Comment: On a Write Once DVD, when closed and ejected, the disc is final at that point. Just make sure Write Once.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 closes the burn session when the disc is ejected, but does
not finalize the disc.

To burn the disc and finalize it requires a third-party program.

For example, use the old but still working
[ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/),
which always generates finalized discs
([link](https://forum.imgburn.com/topic/13105-disc-finalizing/)),
or any of its
[alternative productss](https://alternativeto.net/software/imgburn/?platform=windows).